# Can't read .env file without absolute path

Tags: go, environment-variables

When I try to read the .env file it does not work without using the absolute path.

```
func init() {
    err := godotenv.Load(".env") //<--fails
    //err := godotenv.Load("./.env") //<--fails
    //err := godotenv.Load("/home/peter/Documents/tests/configuration/.env") //<--works
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    Config = GetConfig()
}
```

I get `panic: open .env: no such file or directory`
But the file is there

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  config.go  .env
```

Any clue?

Comment: Where are you running the executable? The working directory of your executable and the package source location are unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potential problem is that the directory you are running the executable from is different than the directory of which the .env file is located. Could you verify this?

Comment: This appears to be the problem. I use Air hot reload which creates the executable in ./tmp and the .env is not there.